# How to propogate deleted user from oauth2 - JHipster, Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta

My JHipster app has some automatic tasks that happen on all users, so I'd like to know if user is deleted from the Identity Provider (in this case Okta):

- Is there any place where this is already implemented?
- If not, I'd welcome suggestions how to implement this?

Comment: This is not implemented in the current version of JHipster. You could use the Okta Java SDK to delete users. https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java

Comment: thank you, if you'll just submit this as an answer I'll accept it :)
If possible, a small sample code will be very appreciated as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not implemented in the current version of JHipster. You could use the Okta Java SDK to delete users. https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java. For example:

```
UserList users = client.listUsers();

// stream
client.listUsers().stream().forEach(user -> {
    user.deactivate();
    user.delete();
});
```

Comment: I implemented using `RestTemplate` directly, the main problem being how to get a `Client` object - if you can expand on that I'd be grateful.

Comment: If you have the correct dependencies in your classpath, you can use dependency injection to get a `Client` instance. See https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-ionic-crypto-java-sdk-example/blob/master/holdings-api/src/main/java/com/okta/developer/holdingsapi/HoldingsController.java#L24 for an example.

Comment: II tried using DI, it wasn't trivial and the REST API is simple enough... an example of DI on top of Jhipster would probably help some people avoid this. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You'll need to add the Okta Java SDK to your build file, its coordinates are `com.okta.spring:okta-spring-sdk`. Then, you’ll need to create an API token. The abbreviated steps are as follows:

1. Log in to your Developer Console
2. Navigate to API > Tokens and click Create Token
3. Give your token a name, then copy its value

Add `okta.client.token=XXX` to your application.yml.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the authority of a token? to only access one app, or perform only certain actions?

Comment: Can you please ask this in a new question since this one is already solved?

Comment: sure, it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690385/is-there-a-way-to-limit-an-okta-token-authority. thanks for all the help.