# Is there a way to limit an Okta token authority?

Tags: okta, okta-api

Following these abbreviated steps to generate an Okta token:

1. Log in to your Developer Console
2. Navigate to API > Tokens and click Create Token
3. Give your token a name

works wonderfully, however I'd like to limit the authority of such a token to only affect certain applications or perform only certain operations - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Tokens share the same rights as the admin that created them.

If you wanted to create an API Token that had read-only access, for instance, you could follow these steps:

1. Assign the Read Only admin role to a user (preferably a service account)
2. Login as that user
3. Create an API Token as usual

That API Token could now only be used for read only operations. An attempt at a write operation with that API Token would fail.

HTH! (full disclosure: I work for Okta)